# Is there any difference between enum : int and enum : const int

Tags: c++11, enums, constants

I just discovered that gcc and clang++, would let me use a `const int` for the underlying type of an enum. I wonder if that has any utility of if for all purposes it is the same as having an enum based on `int`.

I thought that may be it would make the enum instance not assignable, but it was not the case. (And to be honest, I thought it would not compile in the same way that you *can't* make a class derived from a const base type `class C2 : const C1{}`)

**Is there any use or subtle difference between `enum : int` and `enum : const int`?** **If no, why would the compiler allow it?**

Example:

```
#include<iostream>
enum A : const int{ // is this the same as enum A : int ?
   no = 0,
   si
};

int main(){ 
   A a; 
   a = si; // is asignable
   a = no; // twice
   std::cout << (int)a << std::endl; // prints '0'
   return 0;
}
```

---

Funny that I can do this `enum A : volatile int` as well.
(Fortunately, I can't do this `enum A : int&` or `enum A : int*`.)

Comment: The only reason I can think that it allows `const` if the `const` will be ignored, is to support generic programming -- so that if there is a template type that contains enum classes like this, it will work even if a template parameter is `const`. However the programmer can also write `std::remove_const_t` pretty easily, so it's not much difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no difference - the underlaying type for both is int. Here some example test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum e1 : int {};
enum e2: const int {};

int main() {
    bool e1_type = std::is_same<
        const int
       ,typename std::underlying_type<e1>::type
    >::value; 

    bool e2_type = std::is_same<
        const int
       ,typename std::underlying_type<e2>::type
    >::value;

    std::cout
    << "underlying type for 'e1' is " << (e1_type?"const":"non-const") << '\n'
    << "underlying type for 'e2' is " << (e2_type?"const":"non-const") << '\n';
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/dXLDe80zKhSxglcl

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake, here is the relevant standard quote (from C++11 up to latest draft):

> **[dcl.enum]#2** The enumeration type [...] The type-specifier-seq of an enum-base shall name an integral type; **any cv-qualification is ignored**.

where *type-specifier-seq* is the underlying type specification in the corresponding grammar production.